# Pull the last updated record based on the value

Tags: sql

please assist with my relatively simple query if you can.

I would like a SQL query to pull records where for each ID, the Status = 16 was the latest update date.

From this list:

```
ID      Date                  Status
000203E 1988-01-01 00:00:00.000 16
000203E 1970-01-01 00:00:00.000 15
000236S 1970-01-01 00:00:00.000 15
000236S 1982-12-15 00:00:00.000 16
000678W 1996-06-05 00:00:00.000 16
000678W 1970-01-01 00:00:00.000 15
000755U 1984-04-16 00:00:00.000 14
000755U 1970-01-01 00:00:00.000 16
```

Desired output

```
000203E 1988-01-01 00:00:00.000 16
000678W 1996-06-05 00:00:00.000 16
```

Thanks in advance!

Comment: What [tag:rdbms] are you using?

Comment: I don't understand, why only those two? There's two more entries with the status 16.

Comment: I want status of 16 when it is the latest status.  I want the latest date where status = 16.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

One method to get the `id`s is to use aggregation:

```
select id
from t
group by id
having max(date) = max(case when status = 16 then date end);
```

If you want the complete rows, you can use `in` or `exists` or a `join`.  Or just impute the results:

```
select id, max(date) as date, 16 as status
from t
group by id
having max(date) = max(case when status = 16 then date end);
```

Another method to get the complete rows is:

```
select t.*
from t
where t.status = 16 and
      t.date = (select max(t2.date) from t t2 where t2.id = t.id);
```

Answer (score 0):

```
SELECT      table.*
FROM        table
INNER JOIN
(
    SELECT id, max(date) max_date
    FROM table
    WHERE status_id = 16
    GROUP BY id
)           latest_records
ON 
    table.id = latest_records.id
    AND table.date = latest_records.max_date
```

Answer (score 0):

```
SELECT ID, DATE, Status
FROM   YOUR_TABLE T1
INNER JOIN (SELECT   ID, MAX(Date) DATE
            FROM     YOUR_TABLE
            GROUP BY ID) T2
WHERE T1.ID = T2.ID AND T1.DATE = T2.DATE;
```